# Lightpoint following a moving SpriteRenderer whereas it should remain static

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm beginning with Unity3D and I'm having a problem with the lightning.

I made a simple infinite scroller with a road going straight, and I want to add a pointlight in the middle of my screen, in order to have the road at this place enlightened, whereas the remaining is darker.

However, the light seems to follow the middle of my sprite when this one is moving, instead of remaining static.

Here is a gif of what I have:

[image]

My SpriteRenderer has the Sprite/Diffuse material and I added some postprocessing on the camera in order to have a bloom effect on the road.
Do you know what could be the problem here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you have the Light GameObject as a child of the Sprite, so it follows the parent transform

Comment: Hey, thank you for your anwer, 
I checked and both camera and light remain static during the execution

Comment: If you give us more info, like the screenshot of the Hierarchy  we could help you more.

Comment: I checked my camera settings, and the Rendering Path was on "Legacy Vertex Lit". 
Switching it to "Graphics Settings" fixed my issue.